# using a variable with the ZipFile.setpassword command

Tags: python, password-protection, zip

I am working on a script for my class to open a password protected zip file. I have a list of passwords I need to cycle through.

I have create a script that performs the function perfectly when I manually type in the password into the password field: ZipFile.setpassword(b'12345')

But what I want to do is have the variable passwordattempt used instead as it cycles through each entry of my list, like this ZipFile.setpassword (b'passwordattempt') But when I do this it never works and does not seem to be using the password assigned to the variable.

I can see that it is going through my list correctly by using the print(passattempt)

```
#################################
## Create a temp list of pass  ##
## words from the allpass.txt  ##
## file                        ##
#################################

#Create a temp Library
passwordlib = []

#Open temp allpassword file to put into temp list
with open('allpass.txt', 'r+') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip("\n")
        #print(line)
        passwordlib.append(line)
f.close()
#End of temp list creation


#Attempt to open zip file using the list of passwords in passwordlib[]
for line in passwordlib:
        passattempt = line.strip('\n')
        try:
          zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile("Resources/ZippedFiles/testzip.zip", 'r')
          print (passattempt) #Print to confirm passwords are cycling through
          zip_ref.setpassword(b'passattempt')            
          zip_ref.extractall("Resources/ZippedFiles/testout/")
        except:
          pass #if password is incorrect, ignore Runtime error and move to next password      
        zip_ref.close()
```

Comment: Looks like in`zip_ref.setpassword(b'passattempt')` you're passing `passattempt` as string. Try `zip_ref.setpassword(passattempt)`

Comment: I tried that before but then I get an error stating that the item is a string and should be binary so I have to use the b('passattemp'). When I use the test file and password like this zip_ref.setpassword(b'12345') it opens the zip file perfectly.

Comment: Okay, you just have to create another variable and store your `passattempt` as binary in it and then pass it to the `zip_ref`. You can convert using `bin_a = bin(a)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just use `encode` to convert a `string` into `bytes` using the default encoding (utf-8).

```
import zipfile

with open('allpass.txt', 'r+') as f:
    passwordlib = f.readlines()

# Attempt to open zip file using the list of passwords in passwordlib[]
for line in passwordlib:
    passattempt = line.strip('\n')
    with zipfile.ZipFile("file.zip", 'r') as zf:
        print(passattempt)  # Print to confirm passwords are cycling through
        zf.setpassword(passattempt.encode())
        try:
            zf.extractall("Resources/ZippedFiles/testout/")
        except RuntimeError as e:
            if 'Bad password' not in str(e):
                raise
```

Comment: Thanks for this confirmation. I continued researching it and found the same thing about the time this was posted. I finally got it to work, woo hoo!!